# Two way binding and wiring an onChange for a child class

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

I'm new to react and its design pattern, so i tried writing a two way binding and create an onChange for my class and its child, and i was wondering if this is a good thing to do and if its the correct design pattern

I have done something like this :

```
class A extends Component {
    state = {
        BClassProperties: {
            goldAmount: '1',
            silverAmount: '2'
        }
    }

    onBChange = (goldAmount, silverAmount) => {
        const oldBClassProperties = this.state.BClassProperties;

        let newBClassProperties = {...oldBClassProperties};

        newBClassProperties.goldAmount = goldAmount;
        newBClassProperties.silverAmount = silverAmount;

        this.setState({BClassProperties: newBClassProperties})
    }

    render () {
        return (
           <B 
              goldAmount = {this.state.BClassProperties.goldAmount} 
              silverAmount = {this.state.BClassProperties.silverAmount} 
              onChange={this.onBChange}
           />
        )
    }
}

class B extends Component {

onGoldChange = (event) => {
    this.props.onChange(event.target.value, this.props.silverAmount);
};

onSilverChange = (event) => {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.goldAmount, event.target.value);
};

render () {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <input placeholder={"gold"} value={this.props.goldAmount} onChange={this.onGoldChange} />
            <input placeholder={"silver"} value={this.props.silverAmount} onChange={this.onSilverChange} />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
}
```

Is this okay?, are there any better alternatives ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. You are doing it correctly, but your are passing `goldAmount` & `silverAmount` values incorrect.

```
<B 
   goldAmount = {this.state.goldAmount} 
   silverAmount = {this.state.silverAmount} 
   onChange={this.onBChange}
/>
```

Correct way is,

```
<B
  goldAmount={this.state.BClassProperties.goldAmount}
  silverAmount={this.state.BClassProperties.silverAmount}
  onChange={this.onBChange}
/>
```

Also in your `B` component, make your `input` [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html),

```
<input
    placeholder={'gold'}
    value={this.props.goldAmount} //This makes your input controlled
    onChange={this.onGoldChange}
/>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-lzg1l?fontsize=14)

Comment: Thank for the answer but the two mistakes you pointed out are merely the things i forgot to add and fix because i wrote the code on the fly in stack overflow, which i apologize for, the thing i wanted to know the most was if this approach is correct because i'm going to use it everywhere and i don't want a broken design pattern, by the way is there an easier way?, is there a way to share the properties of the B class without having to pass it on using onChange? (will something like redux solve this issue )?

Comment: This is correct approach to share data between components. And more easier way is using `react-redux` - https://react-redux.js.org/

Comment: Also there is another way of using `context` - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Last question, for a project that is going to be big, whats the recommended solution, is there a big gap between the performance of these methods?

Comment: Have a look - https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/07/react-state-vs-redux-state/